# Windows Batch Script for moving files to different Folders based on File Name for Huge Data Volume

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have around 180K files which needs to be move to folders based on the file name.
Files are with different extensions. I need to take all file names which start with numbers and get the number untill the first '-' and make a folder. Move all the files with the number in the folder.
Need to exclude files which do not start with numbers.

> *Sample Data: File Names*
>
> ```
> 123-ACBDHDJ.pdf
>
> 123-dhdjd.txt 
>
> 5658-dgdjdk.txt
>
> 456477-gse.docx
> ```

For example; Based on the above data mentioned on Filenames Above, I want to do the following:

- make folders *123*, *5658* and *456477*
- Move the first two files in folder 123, 3rd file in folder 5658 and
  last file in folder 456477.

**Tried below script:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.psd *.jpg *.html *.tif *.xls *.xlsx *.htm *.csv *.pdf *.docx *.TXT *.zip *.msg *.xlsb *.eml *.*) do (
   echo file found  %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
pause
```

**Issues currently facing:**

1. Folders created with alpha numeric characters as well, I wanted to
   ignore those files and pick only the ones starting with numbers.
2. Script running too long, very slow performance . Data volume is
   very high, 180K records.

Please help with a batch script for this or any faster way to do this as the data volume is very huge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your coding attempts and describe precisely what you have trouble with! Read the [tour] and also these help articles: [ask] and [mcve]. At the moment your "question" is nothing but a code request, which is clearly off-topic here! Thank you! Hint: [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), [`mkdir`](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html), [`move`](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html).

Comment: Added Tried code and Issues faced.

Comment: there is alot of unnecessary for loops, also, you loop each extension type, but eventually do all extensions? also, you never test for numeric numbers, so what if a file is called `test-file.eml`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lot of unnecessary code, which makes your batch file too slow. I would suggest something like:

```bat
@echo off

for %%A IN (*.*) do (
    if not "%%~fA" == "%~f0" (
        echo File found: %%A
        for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%B IN ("%%~nxA") do (
            md %%B>nul
            (move "%%~fA" "%%~dpA%%B")>nul
        )
    )
)
echo Finished
pause
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

It seems also that the other loops you are making are useless. You can directly use `%%~nA`, `%%~xA`, e.t.c. See output of `for /?` in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider why it takes long. You have 128k files, you run 4 loops, meaning the for loops themselfs process each file 5 times, that is 640 000 processes on its own, you then run `echo`s for each, that is even more processes, then we you check if a folder exists and if not create it, the folder exists is another process.. I guess you are getting where I am going with this. You are effectively running over a million procces to complete this task.

Maybe we get rid of all the unwanted for loops, use `*` instead of naming each file, then get rid of delayed expansion as we can simply get away without having to set variables:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
    echo file found  %%i
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ("%%i") do (
     if "%%a-%%b"=="%%i" (
      md %%a>nul
      move "%%~fi" %%a
   )
  )
 )
echo Finished
pause
```

As for the name and extension part, you never use them after setting, If you still want to somewhere use the name and extension of the files, then you just use them without having to set vars:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
   echo file found  %%i
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ("%%i") do (
    if "%%a-%%b"=="%%i" (
       md %%a>nul
       move "%%~fi" %%a
       echo This is the file extension: %%~xi
       echo This is the filename: %%~na
       echo This is the filename, drive and path: %%~dpi
       echo This is the filename with full path: %%~fi
   )
  )
 )
echo Finished
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You may already have an answer with the .bat file scripts. Here is a way to do it in PowerShell. When the script is tested and will move the files correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```
$sourcedir = './s'
$destdir = './d'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path "$sourcedir/*" |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '^(\d+)-.*') {
            $ddir = Join-Path $destdir $Matches[1]
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $ddir)) { New-Item -Name $ddir -ItemType Directory }
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $ddir -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

This can be run from a cmd shell by saving the script into a file (thefile.ps1) and using the following command or putting the command into a .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File thefile.ps1
```

Comment: To run the script from a cmd shell through PowerShell as a -File, you may need to Set the Execution Policy.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way -- see all the explanatory remarks (`rem`) in the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0." & rem /* (directory containing all the files; `%~dp0` points to the
                     rem     parent directory of this batch script; to use the current
                     rem     working directory, simply specify a single `.`) */
set "_MASK=?*-*.*" & rem /* (search pattern to find files, matching only files with at
                     rem     least one hyphen in their names) */
set "_FILTER=^[0123456789][0123456789]*-" & rem /* (`findstr` filter expression;
                     rem     this matches only files whose name begin with one or more
                     rem     decimal digits followed by a hyphen) */

rem // Change to given root directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through all matching files:
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%E in ('
        rem/ Return files and filter out those with non-numeric prefix: ^& ^
            dir /B /A:-D "%_MASK%" ^| findstr /R /I /C:"%_FILTER%"
    ') do (
        rem // Try to create target directory:
        ECHO md "%%E" 2> nul
        rem // Move file into target directory:
        ECHO move /Y "%%E-%%F" "%%E\"
    )
    rem // Return from root directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having tested the script for correct output, **remove both upper-case `ECHO` commands!**